# SQLAlchemy one(): No Results Found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I keep getting a `Traceback` complaining about the system not finding a result. This should not be the case given that the object is actually going through (I know this as I have a print command to confirm what is going through the query). I believe the issue is found in the method of `create_category_rating(..)`.

When I use `.one()`, it throws the complaint I have below. When I use `.all`, it returns `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` (some one else had this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503656/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state)). The [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) at SQLAlchemy does a good job defining these methods, but for some reason my code crashes.

The issue: What is causing the program to break if the object is going through the retrieve method? There is a bug somewhere and I have been struggling with squashing it.

I am using `SQLAlchemy` and `python2.7`:

Traceback:

```
ERROR: notssdb.test.test.test1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 111, in test1
    api.create_category_rating(2, 'Decision-Making', 'baseball', 'Becoming a Leader')
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/convenience.py", line 41, in create_category_rating
    assessment_results = self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 324, in retrieve_assessment_results
    filter(Assessment_Results.owner == owner).one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2478, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
   # output from Traceback 
   Decision-Making
   baseball
   Becoming a Leader
   Becoming a Leader
   test1 <Assessment(name='Becoming a Leader', text='better decisions')>
```

convenience.py 
(create method):

```
def create_category_rating(self, category_rating_int, category_name, username, name):
    category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
    owner = self.retrieve_user(username) # added
    assessment = self.retrieve_assessment(name) #added
    assessment_results = self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_category_rating(category_rating_int, category, assessment_results)
```

object.py 
(retrieve method):

```
def retrieve_assessment_results(self, *args):
    id, assessment, owner = None, None, None
    if len(args) == 1:
        id, = args[0]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        assessment, owner = args
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value being passed is an object')
    if id is not None:
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Results).\
        filter(Assessment_Results.id == id).one()
    elif owner is not None:
        print 'test1', owner
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Results).\
        filter(Assessment_Results.owner == owner).one()
    elif assessment is not None:
        print 'test2', assessment
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Results).\
        filter(Assessment_Results.assessment == assessment).one()
```

Comment: `all()` traceback doesn't contain call to `all()` at all. Please try to open a separate question for the matter as it is difficult for an external examiner try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa cleaned up. I understand what the `.one()` and other methods do... and they work on other queries... so I am confused as to why it is not working here.

Comment: Did you try `filter(Assessment_Results().assessment == assessment).one()` or `Assessment_Results` has already been instanced? Have had a similar problem by just calling the class in the filter and this solved it.

Comment: Thanks @LeandroPoblet it is definitely the query method or the way in which `create_category_rating(...)` is putting the object through. To confirm `Assessment_Results` has been instanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following:

```
self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
```

...but the arguments for "retrieve_assessment_results" is the following (with my comment added)...

```
def retrieve_assessment_results(self, *args):
    id, assessment, owner = None, None, None
    if len(args) == 1:
        id, = args[0]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        assessment, owner = args # Note this line!
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value being passed is an object')
```

You pass owner, then assessment. But if you detect two objects, you will read assessment, then owner. In other words, you are calling the method with one order of objects, and retrieve assuming the reverse order. You can even see this occur in the debug line:

```
print 'test1', owner
```

You'd expect this to print something like `test1 <User(...)>`, but instead it printed...

```
test1 <Assessment(name='Becoming a Leader', text='better decisions')>
```

Also, consider using [Python keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) instead:

```
def retrieve_assessment_results(self, id=None, assessment=None, owner=None):
    ...
```

Then your call becomes less ambiguous:

```
self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner=owner, assessment=assessment)
```

Comment: I completely missed the order of objects! Good catch! Also, the suggestion of using  keyword arguments is fantastic. Now the traceback is complaining about `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` So the good news is that the object is found now.

Answer (score 4):

`one()` will throw an exception if the result set is empty. Use `first()` and you will get the first result or Python `None` if no results are present.

Ditto about `all()` because the question does not contain relevant traceback and code.

Comment: first throws a Traceback as well. I will show the tracebacks above. Something is not right.

Comment: You can always check the state of the database in SQL explorer to see if the data is good or not

Comment: Google for "SQL tools" for your operating system, download an application which looks like friendly and open your database in that application. This is specific to your operating system and datbase, neither of which are mentioned in the question.

Comment: It still isn't working. I believe the issue is with the `retrieve` methods