# Retrieve Method Issue? AttributeError Complaining about 'str' object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, traceback

The issue: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` and I am uncertain how to fix it. 
I believe it is related to the `retrieve` methods below. Someone on [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503656/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state) had a similar issue and it was a simple matter of changing the function...this has not the case for me.

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 132, in test1
    api.retrieve_assessment_result('baseball', 'Becoming a Leader')
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 324, in retrieve_assessment_result
    filter(Assessment_Result.owner == owner).one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 301, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1011, in __eq__
    other, adapt_source=self.adapter))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1338, in _optimized_compare
    state = attributes.instance_state(state)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

object.py

```
def retrieve_assessment_result(self, *args):
    id, owner, assessment = None, None, None
    if len(args) == 1:
        id, = args[0]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        owner, assessment = args
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value being passed is an object')
    if id is not None:
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.id == id).one()
    elif owner is not None:
        print 'test1', owner
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.owner == owner).one()
    elif assessment is not None:
        print 'test2', assessment
        return self.session.query(Assessment_Result).\
        filter(Assessment_Result.assessment == assessment).one()

def create_category_rating(self, category_rating_int, category, assessment_result):
    new_catrating = Category_Rating(category_rating_int, category, assessment_result)
    self.session.add(new_catrating)
    print(new_catrating)
    self.session.commit()
    return(new_catrating)
```

convenience.py 
(inherits from object.py)

```
def create_category_rating(self, category_rating_int, category_name, username, name):
    category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
    owner = self.retrieve_user(username)  
    assessment = self.retrieve_assessment(name)  
    assessment_result = self.retrieve_assessment_result(owner, assessment)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_category_rating(category_rating_int, category, assessment_result)
```

model.py

```
class Category_Rating(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category_ratings'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_rating_int = Column(Integer)

    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.category_id'))
    category = relationship('Category', backref='category_ratings')

    assessment_result_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('assessment_results.id'))
    assessment_result = relationship('Assessment_Result', backref='category_ratings')

    def __init__(self, category_rating_int, category, assessment_result): #OBJECT
        self.category_rating_int = category_rating_int
        self.category = category
        self.assessment_result  = assessment_result

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Category_Rating(category_rating_int='%s')>" % (self.category_rating_int)
```

test.py

```
api = ConvenienceAPI()
api.create_category_rating(2, 'Decision-Making', 'baseball', 'Becoming a Leader')
```

Comment: Please, include [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your model definition. So people can reproduce your error. Also include values you pass as parameters, when you call `create_category_rating(...)`.

Comment: Have you read explanation from linked question? Problem is not changing function. It clearly explains what problem is: "You are assigning a list to a relationship where `uselist=False`. You should set the single model instance, rather than a list containing it.". You're most likely doing the same, when you create `Category_Rating` instance.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Yes, I have. I have posted the requested material now. I am struggling with understanding my own as I am new to all this.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is exactly as the one in the linked question:

> You are assigning a list to a relationship where `uselist=False`. You should set the single model instance, rather than a list containing it.

In your case property `assessment_results` is defined as many-to-one relationship (e.g. single `Category_Rating` can have single `Assessment_Results` instance, but single `Assessment_Results` can have *multiple* `Category_Rating` instances). If you do following renames previous statements will make much more sense for you:

```
assessment_results -> assessment_result
assessment_results_id -> assessment_result_id
Assessment_Results -> Assessment_Result
```

The problem is that `assessment_results` property expects single instance of `Assessment_Results` model, but you set it to result of the method `retrieve_assessment_results()`, which returns list of `Assessment_Results`. That's why it fails.

**UPD**

The second problem is in this string `filter(Assessment_Result.owner == owner).one()`. You try to compare `Owner` instance with string. You probably want to replace it with something like `filter(Owner.name == owner).one()`. Can't tell you exactly without seeing these models definitions.

Comment: Your explanation is highly appreciated! Thank you. Just to clarify: `Assessment_Results` is a table to hold each `Assessment` and their respective `categories`. So a `Assessment_Results` would hold about 4 `category_ratings` per `Assessment_Results` .

Comment: Than my assumption is not correct. You don't need to move relationship definition to `Assessment_Results` model. Just make sure you return *single* instance from `retrieve_assessment_results()` method. Use [`.one()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one) or [`.first()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first) instead of `.all()` depending on your data structure.

Comment: I changed the naming convention (to prevent misunderstanding) so thank you for that! When I do pass `.one()` it returns `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'` So I can update my question to reflect that more accurately w/the Traceback per your suggestion?

Comment: Okey, update question with new code and add new traceback. Or you can debug it yourself. Most likely you assign string instead of model to the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Yaroslav Admin, I did something similar to his suggestion... I added a retrieve method for `assessment_result(..)` in the convenience.py (api) that would check for strings:

**working code:** 
(this inherits from the object.py file -- shown above)

```
def retrieve_assessment_result(self, username, name):
    owner = self.retrieve_user(username)
    assessment = self.retrieve_assessment(name)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).retrieve_assessment_result(owner, assessment)
```